# Covariant typing in method param

Tags: scala

I have the following classes:

```
abstract class Record {}

class Record1 extends Record {}

class Record2 extends Record {}

class MyTable[T <: Record : Manifest] extends externalLibrary.Table[T] {
    def method {}
}

object MyTable1 extends MyTable[Record1] {}

object MyTable2 extends MyTable[Record2] {}
```

And now I'm trying to accept any MyTable subclass in a method parameter

```
def testMethod[T <: MyTable[Record]](t: T) {
    t.method
}

val test = method(MyTable1)
```

This produces the error that MyTable1 does not conform to T.  If I change the method to `[T >: MyTable[Record]]` then this satisfies the type checker at the calling point, but then of course I can't access t.method anymore.  How would I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make classes covariant with a variance annotation at the declaration site:

```
class MyTable[+T <: Record : Manifest]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried that earlier but got a "T is invariant" error, so when I saw your answer I looked around for a solution and wound up changing my `def method(t: T)` methods to `def method[U >: T](u: U)`, which fixed the error